# Automatic test code generation Pycharm with pytest

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

I'm having issues with the `pytest` test autogeneration functionality in PyCharm. I have followed the [official guide of Pycharm to make `pytest` tests](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/pytest.html#create-pytest-test) in which the (summarized) steps are:

1. Install `pytest` and set it as the default test runner.
2. Create a new project with the file `Car.py` as the main file.
3. `Ctrl+Shift+T` with my caret at the `brake()` method and write the same options.

In theory, PyCharm should already import the class `Car` from the file `Car.py` but after accepting the dialogue from step 2 the only thing I get is:

```
def test_brake():
    assert False
```

which cannot be considered a unit test.

Any idea why this happens? Is it a PyCharm bug?